# i can't redirect from signup to signin page in string

Tags: spring, redirect

i try to sign up to page and after complete sign it give me 404 page after successful save in db 
this is my controller

```
    package com.Kwn.controller;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.Kwn.model.User;
import com.Kwn.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class BasicOperation {
    public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BasicOperation.class);
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView regestration(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("email") String email,
            @RequestParam("password") String password, @RequestParam("repeatedPass") String repeatedPass) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setUserName(username);
        if (!password.equals(repeatedPass)) {
            ModelAndView obj = new ModelAndView("redirect:/Signup");
            log.info("not equalivant password");
            return obj;
        } else
            user.setPassword(password);

        userService.saveUser(user);
        log.info("success login");
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/login");
    }

}
```

and this is my project structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJuw3.png)

and this is spring configuration for viewresolver and resource handler

```
package com.Kwn.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.PathMatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.Kwn")
public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * Configure ViewResolvers to deliver preferred views.
     */
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/View/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    /**
     * Configure ResourceHandlers to serve static resources like CSS/ Javascript
     * etc...
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/");
    }

    /**
     * Configure Converter to be used. In our example, we need a converter to
     * convert string values[Roles] to UserProfiles in newUser.jsp
     */

    /**
     * Configure MessageSource to lookup any validation/error message in
     * internationalized property files
     */
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    /**
     * Optional. It's only required when handling '.' in @PathVariables which
     * otherwise ignore everything after last '.' in @PathVaidables argument.
     * It's a known bug in Spring [https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6164],
     * still present in Spring 4.1.7. This is a workaround for this issue.
     */
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer matcher) {
        matcher.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(true);
    }
}
```

and when i press on register button it redirect me to 404 page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your issue is not security as it is 404, you are redirect to "/login" and don't have request mapping for that, so If you're configured the viewer resolver well, you don't need to add redirect to your return string here "redirect:/login" just return "login" assuming that the viewer resolver prefix is "/view" and suffix is ". jsp" this will render login page after finishing singup.

Answer (score 0):

Server can not find /login,
you should make a new request mapping method that handles requests on this path and returns the right page

```
RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public ModelAndView login() {
    return new ModelAndView("login");
}
```

Comment: i can't make any redirect in side the app itself till when i try to redirect from index.jsp to login.jsp or signup.jsp return 404
 and this is the code i use to redirect
` <body>
 <h2>Hello World!</h2>
 <c:redirect url="/Signup"></c:redirect>
</body> `